# Why events are not fired from dojo widget elements?

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I having the difficulty of dojo widgets not firing the events.

I have tried with `dojo.query` to bind events to certain elements, but it doesn't fire events.
So I tried with `dijit.registry`. But it too doesn't fire events on clicking the element.

**HTML**

```
<div class="buttons">
     <input id="radio1" type="radio" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/RadioButton" name="radiobtn" /> <label for="radio1">one</label>
     <input id="radio2" type="radio"  data-dojo-type="dijit/form/RadioButton" name="radiobtn" /> <label for="radio2">Two</label>
     <input id="radio3" type="radio" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/RadioButton" name="radiobtn" /> <label for="radio3">Three</label>
 </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
require(["dojo/parser", "dojo/query", "dijit/registry", "dijit/form/RadioButton", "dojo/domReady!"], function(parser, query, registry) {
    parser.parse();

    on(query('.buttons input'), 'click', function() {
        alert('Clicked');           
     });   

    on(registry.byId('radio1'), 'click', function() {
        alert('Clicked Radio1');    
    });   
});
```

Here is [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3NG4f/1/) of this issue.

How to trigger events with `dojo.query` to dojo widget element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. If you read the [reference guide](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/on.html) you will notice that the `dojo/on` module is used only for DOM events. Your widget uses DOM nodes as well, but they should not be used as they're encapsulated by the [widget events](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dijit/form/RadioButton.html).

To register an event handler you should use the [`on()`](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dijit/form/RadioButton#1_9dijit_form_RadioButton_on) function, for example:

```
registry.byId("radio1").on("click", function() {
    console.log("Clicked");
});
```

I also updated your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/3NG4f/3/).

---

If you really want to use `dojo/query` (to handle multiple radio buttons), then you can do that by using [`byNode()`](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dijit/registry#1_9dijit_registry_byNode) of the `dijit/registry` module to access the widget based on that DOM node. For example:

```
query(".dijitRadio").forEach(function(domNode) {
    registry.byNode(domNode).on("click", function() {
        console.log("Clicked");
    });
});
```

But you have to watch out with this. The `input` field is gone when the DOM node is converted to a widget and replaced by a template that `dijit/form/RadioButton` uses. The best way to get the DOM node of the radiobutton is by using the `dijitRadio` class.

Another update of your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/3NG4f/4/).

---

**Small note**: It might be a better idea to handle the `onChange` event if you're interested in the change of state of a radio button (on/off).

Comment: Is there any way where some widgets can be bind events combinely? That is widgets with same classes need to fire a common function.

Comment: I updated my answer with something that might solve it. But in stead of using the `.dijitRadio` selector you probably want the `.buttons .dijitRadio` selector.